# CASE Statement in Script not segmenting rows for comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Good day. I have a table called `subObjGroup`.  I am selecting from this table and performing a case statement against a a few columns. I am looking at the `typeCol` column in order to classify which appropriate nested case operators to use.

The issue is that when it performs the statement, I am getting incorrect results for the `vCheck` column. I am not getting the data based on the case statement criteria. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Are there behind the scenes 'hooks' or 'links' that carry when the numid and value are the same? Any help is most appreciated.

subObjGroup Table with incorrect results in `vCheck` column

```
groupid eventid numid   tagVal  greaterThan greaterEqThan   lessThan    lessEqThan  equalTo typeCol vCheck  activeid    getVal
28      18      9000001 NULL    NULL        NULL            105         NULL        NULL        3       1    68         92.907
9       19      9000001 NULL    NULL        NULL            105         NULL        NULL        3       1    68         92.907
10      20      9000001 NULL    105         NULL            NULL        NULL        NULL        1       0    68         92.907
```

Desired Results please look at the `vCheck` column

```
groupid eventid numid   tagVal  greaterThan greaterEqThan   lessThan    lessEqThan  equalTo typeCol vCheck  activeid    getVal
28      18      9000001 NULL    NULL        NULL            105         NULL        NULL        3       0    68         92.907
9       19      9000001 NULL    NULL        NULL            105         NULL        NULL        3       0    68         92.907
10      20      9000001 NULL    105         NULL            NULL        NULL        NULL        1       1    68         92.907
```

The Script

```
DECLARE @nID nvarchar(50)
SET @nID = '9000001'

SELECT
  g.groupid,
  g.eventid,
  g.numid,
  g.tagVal,
  g.greaterThan,
  g.greaterEqThan,
  g.lessThan,
  g.lessEqThan,
  g.equalTo,
  g.typeCol,
  vCheck =
          CASE
            WHEN g.typecol = 0 THEN CASE
                WHEN g.getVal = g.tagval THEN 0
                ELSE 1
              END
            WHEN g.typecol = 1 THEN CASE
                WHEN g.getVal > g.greaterthan THEN 0
                ELSE 1
              END
            WHEN g.typecol = 2 THEN CASE
                WHEN g.getVal >= g.greatereqthan THEN 0
                ELSE 1
              END
            WHEN g.typecol = 3 THEN CASE
                WHEN g.getVal < g.lessthan THEN 0
                ELSE 1
              END
            WHEN g.typecol = 4 THEN CASE
                WHEN g.getVal <= g.lesseqthan THEN 0
                ELSE 1
              END
            WHEN g.typecol = 5 THEN CASE
                WHEN g.getVal = g.equalto THEN 0
                ELSE 1
              END
            ELSE 0
          END,
  g.activeid,
  g.getVal

FROM subobjgroup g
WHERE numid = @nID
```

Comment: You many need to handle null comparisons better by using `isNull(val1, val2)` or `coalesce(val1, val2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the logic is simply backwards (you have "1" and "0" mixed up in the subcases).

However, I think this logic is more simply written as:

```
vCheck = (CASE WHEN g.typecol = 0 AND g.getVal = g.tagval THEN 1
               WHEN g.typecol = 1 AND g.getVal > g.greaterthan THEN 1
               WHEN g.typecol = 2 AND g.getVal >= g.greatereqthan THEN 1
               WHEN g.typecol = 3 AND g.getVal < g.lessthan THEN 1
               WHEN g.typecol = 4 AND g.getVal <= g.lesseqthan THEN 1
               WHEN g.typecol = 5 AND g.getVal = g.equalto THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END),
```